# Need help lowering 5.5V to 3V for my GPIO input

Tags: resistors

So I'm new to electronics and sorry for the cursed images of circuits, but I have a background in computer science and trying to make this work.

So I took the connection from my Intercom bell and it's 5.5V, I plan to connect it to the input pin of my Raspberry pi, but the max voltage for GPIO is 3.3V and I don't want to damage the pin, so I put a couple of resistors(serial, 0.2M ohm) and expected the voltage to drop. But the current is so low that resistors have minimal to no impact on voltage.

So how can I lower the voltage to stable 3V to use it as a signal when somebody is ringing the bell.

Ty for any answer.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Use a resistor voltage divider. Not series resistors by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

**You have many options**, most common being **resistor voltage divider, linear voltage regular, buck converter and using transistor/relay to pass 3.3V from pin 1 to pin x**, seems like you already have resistors so the first one might be the easier option, to calculate the second resistor use this: R2=(Vout * R1)/(Vin - Vout).

[image]